# How to send multiple information in mail using java mail API

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am using java mail to send mail to a sender.But my problem is that i am not able to send multiple information in one mail body only one information is coming.But i want to send multiple information in one mail ,Here i have so far

```
 Properties props = System.getProperties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.user", senderEmail);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", gmail);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    // Required to avoid security exception.
    MyAuthenticator authentication =  new MyAuthenticator(senderEmail,senderMailPassword);
    Session session =  Session.getInstance(props,authentication);
    session.setDebug(true);

    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderEmail));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(recipeintEmail));
    /*message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,InternetAddress.parse(WebConstants.AdminMail));*/
    message.setSubject("Password Recovery mail");
    message.setText(resetLink);
    message.setText("1236547");
    message.setText("Here is another text");
    message.setContent(messageText, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    //message.setText(messageText);

    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
    transport.connect(gmail,port, senderEmail, senderMailPassword);
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

    transport.close();
```

My problem is that only the first setText is working,not the other two.Can anyone help??

Comment: why you cant add your texts?

Comment: its not  working  only the first one is coming

Comment: What `My problem is that only the first setText is working,not the other two` means?

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call

```
message.setText("whatever")
```

it will overwrite the text you've previously set.

And then, your final call to

```
message.setContent(messageText, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

will again overwrite everything with whatever is stored in `messageText` (in your case apparently the same value as the value of `resetLink`).

---

Try like this, by first using a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build your message contents, and then inserting it into your message:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(resetLink).append(System.lineSeparator());
sb.append("1236547").append(System.lineSeparator());
sb.append("Here is another text");

message.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: I would like to add that some sort of template engine like velocity or freemarker offer a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I wholeheartedly agree, but taking the current level of the question into account, I think that integrating a template engine might be a couple of bridges too far.

Comment: It was more a suggestion for voluntary exercise for the OP ;)